# Cytoscape installation

Tags: cytoscape

We would like to install Cytoscape on a server (Windows or Linux) and allow multiple users to connect simultaneously using a client software. Is this possible, and if so, what are requirements in regards to the server and the client software?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly that's possible.  There aren't any particular requirements, but keep in mind that for large networks, Cytoscape likes lots of memory.  At any rate, we use X2Go on our Linux servers and it works really well for Cytoscape.  Keep in mind, however, that a CytoscapeConfiguration directory will be created in each user's home and that apps and configuration information will be stored there.