# using cytoscape on server

Tags: server, bioinformatics, cytoscape

i am trying to implement cytoscape in my lab and have installed it on the centralized server which we access via ssh from own terminals (with x11 forwarding).

i did find an answer by [Scooter Morris to the question by RNA123 here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838468/cytoscape-installation)
and currently my cytoscape 3.8.2 installation (as root) in /opt/ works by executing it as non-root user. however, if a second user launches it while an instance is already running, it throws the error:

> karaf: There is a Root instance already running with name Cytoscape
> 3.8.2 and pid 121496. If you know what you are doing and want to force the run anyway, export CHECK_ROOT_INSTANCE_RUNNING=false and re run
> the command.

is there a way to have a centralised installation of cytoscape and have multiple users access it from their own terminals? or is it safe to do:

> CHECK_ROOT_INSTANCE_RUNNING=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I posted on BioStars:

> Yes, it should be safe, although there are some caveats. Once you get
> past the "CHECK_ROOT_INSTANCE_RUNNING" you'll get an error about "port
> already open". This is because Cytoscape attempts to open a port for
> it's REST interface. You can easily wrap the Cytoscape launch in a
> python or shell script that randomizes the port to avoid that problem,
> but if you have users using RCy3 or py4cytoscape, they would have to
> know the port to connect to. The best solution, especially in an hpc
> environment, is to run Cytoscape in a docker or singularity container
> and map the REST port "1234" to something user-specific.

I'll add one more comment here.  That last part about mapping the REST port is really important.  If nobody maps the REST port and a second user launches Cytoscape and then uses CyREST, they will "take control" of the first user's Cytoscape.  Definitely not what you want.

-- scooter